# Video gets paused when zoom pressed using Youtube API in Android app

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I have integrated the Android YouTube API in my Android app. It's working properly but whenever I click the zoom button the video gets paused. I have to play the video again.

Is there any way I can make it continue to play even after the zoom button is pressed (I mean the video is zoomed). Is it possible?

And does the API work in devices under level 16 like level 11 or 12? I don't have a device lower than level 16, that's why I'm asking.

EDIT: For those guys who want to see some code.

This is what I did to initialize the YouTube API:

```
youtubeplayerview.initialize(API_KEY, this);
```

And in onInitializationSuccess method I used this to load the video:

```
player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);
```

And in my XML I did this:

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
 android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

EDIT 2: My setOnFullscreenListener inside onInitializationSuccess method

```
player.setOnFullscreenListener(new OnFullscreenListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onFullscreen(boolean fullscreen)
    {
        if(fullscreen)
           player.play();
        else
           player.play();
    }
});
```

Please clear my doubt rather than just suggesting edits.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes,it will work on those devices.for play/pause issue.plz post some code

Comment: you can implement an interface `YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener` and resume video when you go fullscreen. Reference: `https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications#Custom_Fullscreen_Handling`

Comment: Can you please post some more code. Or give an answer with a bit of more code, I'm not at all habituated with this YouTube API, its totally new topic for me

Comment: I would have already posted it if I have that right now.I can just guide if you implement it.

Comment: Ok I got your     OnFullscreenListener  i created the listener inside the    onInitializationSuccess method but its not working, but this is a listener if the player is in full screen mode if I am coming out of the full screen mode then also the video shouldn't be paused I didn't find any zoom control listener

Comment: you will get callback on `onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen)` method.`isFullscreen` will be true when you go fullscreen and it will be false when you come out of fullscreen

Comment: Please check the edit I made in the Question just now

Comment: yes,that is fine.is it working for you now?

Comment: No that wasn't enough, I checked the YouTube API and there they are handling fullscreen behaviour by themselves, so I added this line     player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);     now its not pausing when I zoom in/out

Comment: ok.that is what I have mentioned in comment by providing this url `https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications#Custom‌​_Fullscreen_Handling` . anyways, you should post your working code snippet so that it can be helpful to other developers in future.

Answer (score 0):

I think the YouTube API doesn't provide fullscreen view without pausing the video, even in the youtubeapidemo from google also has different approach,

I checked out the API demo  and got to this solution that without pausing the video you have to handle fullscreen behaviour yourself.

Inside your onInitializationSuccess method use this

```
player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
```

if you don't want the video to be fullscreen from the start then

```
player.setFullscreen(false);
```

otherwise set it as true 
then inside that method only do something like this:

```
player.setOnFullscreenListener(new OnFullscreenListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onFullscreen(boolean fullscreen)
    {
        if(fullscreen)
        {
            player.play();
            fltop.setVisibility(View.GONE);             
        }
        else
        {
            player.play();
            fltop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                                      
        }
    }
});
```

Here my fltop is the top part of my layout, I'm setting the visibility gone so that it looks really fullscreen.

Thanks to Mehul Joisar for helping me out with this.